# How to auto deploy to Azure with https ssl

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I made auto deploy to azure from tfs (AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml). It's perfect work on port 80. But I need https in 443. How can I configure project, that it auto deploy on https with ssl?